# State to props with getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

So im trying to make a component that request data from a server and i want to able to change it before i submit it somewhere else previously i would have done it li

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.dwelling) {
        this.state.dwelling = nextProps.dwelling;
    }
    if (!nextProps.saving && this.props.saving) {
        this.props.history.push('/users');
    }
}
}
```

note: the second if is also very usfull to push after a successful save.

but since componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated i was trying to do the same with getDerivedStateFromProps:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.dwelling !== prevState.dwelling) {
        return {dwelling: nextProps.dwelling}
    }
    return null
}
```

Problem is getDerivedStateFromProps is called after every render method and is messing with my onChange handlers, is there any replacement for componentWillReceiveProps? i saw a post about using shouldComponentUpdate but it seems that is not the intended way to use the method.

EDIT:
componentDidUpadte did the job:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.dwelling !== prevProps.dwelling){
        this.setState(() => ({dwelling: this.props.dwelling}));
    }
}
```

Comment: _getDerivedStateFromProps is called after every render method_ Yes `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be called when you change the state, or props are changed. If you want to prevent rendering on `props` change, then use the `shouldComponentUpdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your componentWillReceiveProps example, you shouldn't be setting state directly. Instead, you should be calling `this.setState`.

However, to answer your question... are there reasons you wouldn't choose to do this in `componentDidUpdate`? That might be better than using `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: Note: `componentDidUpdate` will cause a re render on a `setState` call, which `getDerivedStateFromProps` will not.

Comment: Correct, though as a static method, I'd argue that `getDerivedStateFromProps` is not a great place to do side-effects like pushing to history in OP's example.

Comment: never tought about componentDidUpdate! thanks, btw is that the correct way to use functional setstate? i added the solution to my post